# gcc compiler report warning but a.out works smoothly otherwise

Tags: c, array-initialization, designated-initializer

I am following the book "C Primer Plus" and encounter such a snippet of code:

```
// designate.c -- use designated initializers
#include <stdio.h>
#define MONTHS 12
int main(void) 
{
    int days[MONTHS] = {31, 28, [4] = 31, 30, 31, [1] = 29};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MONTHS; i++)
        printf("%2d %d\n", i+1, days[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

It reports errors when I compiled it:

```
$ cc designate.c
designate.c:6:57: warning: initializer overrides prior initialization of this subobject [-Winitializer-overrides]
    int days[MONTHS] = {31, 28, [4] = 31, 30, 31, [1] = 29};
                                                        ^~
designate.c:6:29: note: previous initialization is here
    int days[MONTHS] = {31, 28, [4] = 31, 30, 31, [1] = 29};
                            ^~
1 warning generated.
```

Nonetheless, `./a.out` works properly.

```
$ ./a.out
 1 31
 2 29
 3 0
 4 0
 5 31
 6 30
 7 31
 8 0
 9 0
10 0
11 0
12 0
```

I am very confused here about what should I learn from the error report?

Comment: Hmm, the warning could hardly be more explicit....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true that the warnings are often about serious issues, this one just says that something that you do doesn't make much sense and could be an oversight. Specifically

```
int days[MONTHS] = {31, 28, [4] = 31, 30, 31, [1] = 29};
```

Here you're having `28` for element 1, and then you're overwriting it to `29` with `[1] = 29`. So that `28` is gone, and that's what it warns you about. It translates to this:

```
int days[MONTHS] = {31, 29, 0, 0, 31, 30, 31};
```

And as you can see from your results:

```
1 31
2 29
3 0
4 0
5 31
6 30
```

The `28` indeed is gone. The compiler doesn't know how important that `28` was to you, perhaps it was very important and `[1] = 29` was a typo. That's why it warns you. And as you can also see, there's some whackiness with March and April having `0` days going on, surely this isn't what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you set the arr[0]= 31, arr[1] =28 , arr[4]= 31 and so on. when you set [1] = 29 you reset the var in place arr[1] which was 28 to 29.